# Неверная ссылка в разделе справки "Кто такие модераторы и какова их роль?"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, справка, тревоги

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас ссылка ведёт на ту же самую страницу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators.

Но если верить оригинальной статье справки https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators, то должна вести на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв! Внес необходимые изменения.